# If my 2 class constructors have the same number of args, why does it matter that the base class's constructor doesn't have 0 args?

Tags: c#, .net

```
namespace DnD
{
    class Player : Creature
    {
        Race race;
        Spell[] cantrips = new Spell[16];
        public Player(Race inputRace)
        {
            race = inputRace;         
        }

        void castSpell(Spell spell)
        {
            
        }
    }

    class Creature
    {
        String name;
        public int hp;

        Creature(string inputName)
        {
            name = inputName;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, this code gives me an error that the base class (creature) has a constructor with more that zero args, with the exact error message being:
`'Creature' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'`

I have seen something like this on another post, though there the base class' constructor has 1 arg and the derived class' had zero but in this case they both have 1.

Also this code is from my project where i am tryng to somewhat make dnd in c#.

Comment: How should `Player` construct its base `Creature`? The error message is reminding you that you didn't say how that should be done.

Comment: Please get in the habit of [reading the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors) before asking questions about such basic syntax.

Comment: I think [this documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base#example-2) is pretty much your situation.  You just have to use the `base` keyword to call the base constructor.  Since there is no parameterless constructor, you have to give the base constructor its argument explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the fact that *if you don't write `:base(...)` after your constructor definition, C# writes `:base()` for you* (and to be fair, it isn't obvious)

Every constructor has to make a call to a base constructor, all the way up the descent tree to object. If you don't provide instruction on which constructor to call C# calls one for you (invisibly). If there isn't such a constructor, C# cannot sort that out itself automagically; you have to provide direction

If you don't provide a constructor, C# provides an empty one that does nothing, just so it can establish a chain. If you do provide one, it doesn't provide one (but it might still modify yours to call base)

So, if you write:

```
class NoConstructor{


}
```

C# modifies it to:

```
class NoConstructor{

  NoConstructor():base(){}
}
```

---

If you write:

```
class ConstructorNoBase{
  ConstructorNoBase(){}
}
```

C# modifies it to:

```
class ConstructorNoBase{
  ConstructorNoBase():base(){}
}
```

---

If you write:

```
class ConstructorWithBase{
  ConstructorWithBase():base{}
}
```

C# leaves it alone

---

You can this reach a situation where you have:

```
class Parent{
  Parent(int arg){

  }
}

class Child:Parent{

}

class Child2:Parent{
  Child2(int arg){

  }
}
```

And C# modifies them to:

```
class Parent{
  Parent(int arg):base(){ //no problem; object has a no-arg constructor

  }
}

class Child:Parent{
  Child():base(){    //problem, there isn't a no-arg base constructor
  }
}

class Child2:Parent{
  Child2(int arg):base(){   //problem, there isn't a no-arg base constructor

  }
}
```

Particularly in the second case, C# won't look at Child2 and go "oh, there is a `int arg` constructor on the parent, and `int arg` on the child, I'll call `base(arg)`" - it just puts `base()` in

To stop it creating this "call to something that doesn't exist" you either have to:

- provide the thing it is calling so it does exist
- provide your own call to `base(...)` to stop c# inserting its own call

Comment: The message i'm getting is that is need to put base's constructor's args into ` : base()` on my dervied class though when i put only 1 arg in like `string inputName` it seems to think that that's 2, which is confusing me a lot. Also, when I put in just the data types it tells me it's an invalid expression term.

Comment: Your base class Creature has no constructor that takes 0 arguments. C# doesn't add one. Your sub class Playet has no call to `:base(something_here)` so c# adds `:base()` which calls something that doesn't exist. Choose what you want to do: 1) add a no-argument constructor to Creature or 2) add a call to `:base(some_string_here)` to Player's constructor.

Comment: After you have chosen, if you chose 1) add a `Creature()` constructor to Creature. If you chose 2) you think of some useful valid string that Player has access to, that can be given to Creature's base. What string would you want to give?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call the base class constructor with `:base (someString)`. You don't show the `Race` class here, but if it had a `string RaceName` property, you could pass that to the base class constructor.

```
public Player(Race inputRace)
    : base (inputRace.RaceName)
{
    race = inputRace;         
}
```

Also, consider if the `Creature` class should ever have a concrete instance. This is probably a good candidate for an abstract class.